# How to set InteliJ code style definitions in away that will differentiate between regular calls and builders

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

[image]Our team's InteliJ common code style contain the following definition:

Editor-> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Chained method calls:
"Wrap if long"

The problem is that we would like have this behavior for builders:

```
foo().
.addA()
.addB()
.addC()
.build();
```

And this behavior for regular calls:

```
foo().methodA().methodB().methodC();
```

Is there any way to configure it this way ?

Comment: How do you expect this to work? How would IntelliJ IDEA detect that a call is a builder?

Comment: I was hoping that chained calls with the last call "build()" will be detected as builder.

Comment: There is no possibility to configure formatting depending on the names of the methods being called. (Just imagine what the UI for such a feature would look like.)